# Was the reference to Jodrell Bank in 'Spyfall' a continuity error?

Tags: doctor-who

It has been suggested in [this](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2020-01-05/doctor-who-spyfall-jodrell-bank/) and other articles that the reference in *Spyfall* to a previous encounter between The Doctor and The Master at Jodrell Bank is a continuity error.

In *Spyfall*, The Doctor says that being at the top of the Eiffel tower is "*worse than Jodrell Bank*." "*Did I ever apologise for that?*" the Master asks.

This appears to refer to the finale of *Logopolis* in which the two battle at the top of a radio telescope, resulting in the Fourth Doctor falling and having to regenerate. However, in the classic serial the location is referred to as 'The Pharos Project'. The scenes were also not filmed at the real Jodrell Bank, even though they were originally planned to be.

Although the article suggests some *possibilities*, it does not seem to be able to assert a definite answer.

Is this a continuity error? Did Chibnall mistaken assume the location in *Logopolis* was Jodrell Bank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly reasonable to assume that Jodrell Bank and *The Pharos Project* are the same thing - or that the fictional *project* refers to a particular program of research that took place at the real-life radio telescope.

Consider the timeline:

- The real Jodrell Bank was built in **1945**.
- Jodrell Bank was mentioned in the *First Doctor* story *The Tenth Planet* in **1966**.
- The fictional *Pharos Project* featured in *Logopolis* was a scientific research installation with the goal of contacting alien intelligence. The episode was set in the year the serial was broadcast, **1981**.

As a model of the Lovell telescope at Jodrell Bank was used in *Logopolis* even though it was not filmed on location there, it seems that the production was deliberately set at this location. As the site already existed in the Doctor Who universe, they must, therefore, be the same place.

Comment: There was also a radio telescope in the 2nd Doctor story 'Terror of the Autons' at Beacon Hill, where ever that is.

Comment: @jim Beacon Hill is another real-life radio station in Devon. In the seventies at least, Jodrell seemed to be the leading station in the UK - it also gets mentioned in the list of worldwide telescopes that failed to notice the Vogons in *Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy*.

Comment: Since these telescopes do such a poor job of detecting aliens, it makes you wonder why we keep building them...